# Huawei Site Kit is returning Error Code 6

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to develop an android application using Huawei Site Kit. I am following this codelab at the moment : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSSiteKit/index.html#0 I did everything exactly what codelab says but when I run my application it is throwing an error and in the log it is saying "**Error Code 6**"

Did anybody received same error before and solved it? Help me please

Comment: Probably related with my question. My map was working fine in the morning but now it's just displaying a white screen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606479/huawei-map-is-not-rendering-and-displays-white-screen-returns-http-status-code-5

Comment: did u solved that issue ? i am facing the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the API token is invalid,
I searched the official docs and found the list of error codes.
They may help.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/hms-site-result-code

Its specifically for site kit only.

Answer (score 0):

searchService = SearchServiceFactory.create(getActivity(), API_KEY);

It seems API key is invalid.